# Selenion WebDriver Instagram Bot not liking pictures

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bots, instagram-api

I know it's better to do a INSTAGRAM API based bot but I had made a selenium firefox one that was working a couple of months ago but know that I wanted to run it again it's not liking pictures anymore

```
   def like_photo(self, hashtag):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/" + hashtag + "/")
        time.sleep(2)

        # gathering photos
        pic_hrefs = []
        for i in range(1, 7):
            try:
                driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
                time.sleep(2)
                # getting hashtags
                hrefs_in_view = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
                # finding hrefs
                hrefs_in_view = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in hrefs_in_view
                                 if '.com/p/' in elem.get_attribute('href')]
                # building list of photos
                [pic_hrefs.append(href) for href in hrefs_in_view if href not in pic_hrefs]
            except Exception:
                continue

        # Liking photos
        unique_photos = len(pic_hrefs)
        for pic_href in pic_hrefs:
            driver.get(pic_href)
            time.sleep(2)
            try:
                time.sleep(random.randint(2, 4))
                like_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/article/div[2]/section[1]/span[1]/button').click()
                # liking photo
                like_button().click()
                time.sleep(random.randint(1, 2))
            except Exception as e:
                time.sleep(2)
            unique_photos -= 1
```

Above is the code for gathering photos by a given hashtag and then liking them, the gathering part works fine but the liking doesn't happen. Perhaps it's a problem with the XPATH? That's what I though at first but if that's the case which one should I use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is indeed working properly and you should only change the line where you look for the like_button

Instead of:

```
like_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/article/div[2]/section[1]/span[1]/button').click()
```

Use this:                 `like_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@aria-label="Like"]').click()`

Answer (score 0):

If it worked before and if you did not changed the code it may be because the site has a little bit changed

I recommend to use xpath the less possible and prioritize the Id name class... if they don’t have an unique one on some navigators you can right click on the elements in the inspector and copy the xpath

Also with your code you only click on one like if you want to like them all do:

```
Likes=driver.findElementsById(id)

for x in likes:
    x.click()
```

Comment: I copied the Xpath with right click and doesn't work, I used class name 'button' and automatically followed everyone in the hashtag so the rest of the code works I just need to know how to properly get the like button @rafalou38